# SharePoint 2013 top link navigation bar size differ for few pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css

In home(some other pages also) page header size is normal as shown below.

[image]

If I'm moving to other pages the size gets differs blow image.

[image]

When I checked the corev15.css file for its style

```
.ms-core-pageTitle{font-size: 2.77em;}
```

How to make top navigation bar size same on all pages.

Comment: And your question is what exactly?

Comment: Link size should be same on all the pages

Comment: Where does the different font sizes come from? Both from corev15.css? How are the classes different?

Comment: i have checked it by selecting inspect element in IE browser. It is showing same class. If i am changing the .ms-core-pageTitle{font-size: 2.77em;} to 1.77em it looks better but other other pages it looks too small.

Comment: How about just setting the font size to a real value like "font-size: 16px"? Also set it to "!important", just in case there is any other CSS refering to the same. "em" is a relative size, so I guess it catches different basic / relative values on your sites.

Comment: Even i tried it by giving px values. same issue happening

Comment: As per SteffPoint's comment, give px value with !important like: ".ms-core-pageTitle{font-size: 20px !important;}" attach this css in master page or in your css which is referred in masterpage.

Comment: an we able to write our own class for this navigation bar?